# JSON Parse to get objects within array

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing, ecmascript-5

I've never done anything like this before and are struggling to get this working, I have tried different code samples online but to no joy.

I want to return the `displayName` from the 5 objects in the below array.

[image: array example]

[image: first]

I'm restricted to only use ES5.

I tried the below but was only getting the first object when printing rather than all 5.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < parsed.value.length; i++) {
    var counter = parsed.value[i].displayName;
}
```

Any tips/points? As you can tell I'm new to this!

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is you were doing something with `counter` after loop finished. You didn't really show much code in that loop to know how you use that variable

Comment: I recommend you do not use images for this type of questions it is easier to collaborate if you provide a code to copy and start working. It also allows you to avoid hiding sensitive information. These, among other advantages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a look at the below simple examples.

> These examples do not include all the fields from your input data but relevant.
>
> I think, it will be helpful.

```
var parsed = {
    value:  [
        {fullName:  "Ken Thompson",  displayName:  "Ken",  age:  55}, 
        {fullName:  "Rob Pike",  displayName:  "Rob",  age:  50}, 
        {fullName:  "Robert Griesemer",  displayName:  "RobertGoog",  age:  56}, 
        {fullName:  "Ander Hezlsberg",  displayName:  "AndersMicro",  age:  58}, 
        {fullName:  "Ryan Dahl",  displayName:  "Ryan08",  age:  40}
     ]
};

// 1st way to get as an array of objects
var dispNames = parsed.value.map(function(o) { return {displayName: o.displayName}});
console.log(dispNames);

/*
[ { displayName: 'Ken' },
  { displayName: 'Rob' },
  { displayName: 'RobertGoog' },
  { displayName: 'AndersMicro' },
  { displayName: 'Ryan08' } ]
*/

// 2nd way to get as a list of displayNames
var dispNames2 = parsed.value.map(function(o) { return o.displayName});
console.log(dispNames2);
/*
    [ 'Ken', 'Rob', 'RobertGoog', 'AndersMicro', 'Ryan08' ]
*/

// 3rd way to get as a string with displayNames separated with comma(,) 
console. log(dispNames2.join(","));
/*
    Ken,Rob,RobertGoog,AndersMicro,Ryan08
*/
```

If you want to get result as the above 3rd way shows,  here is most simple way to get that without using **join()** method defined on array objects.

```
console.log("" + dispNames2);
// Ken,Rob,RobertGoog,AndersMicro,Ryan08
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much! It is exactly what I was looking to achieve. I can see the map function being very useful for me in other cases too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you need, but I think it will work :

```
var names = parsed.value.map(function(v){ return v.displayName });
```

Now `names` is an array containing all the `displayName` values.

If you want objects with just the `displayName` property, then :

```
var objects = parsed.value.map(function(v) { 
   return {
      displayName: v.displayName
   };
});
```

You can check [MDN doc for map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

As Johnny5 suggests, the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is the ideal in this case. Try this approximation where you get an array of objects like the original dataset

```js
const dataset = [
    {
        classification: null,
        createdDateTime: new Date('2018-03-03'),
        deletedDateTime: null,
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
        displayName: 'John Logan',
        mail: 'john.logan@domain.com',
    }, {
        classification: null,
        createdDateTime: new Date('2018-03-03'),
        deletedDateTime: null,
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
        displayName: 'Ken Master',
        mail: 'ken.master@domain.com',
    }, {
        classification: null,
        createdDateTime: new Date('2018-03-03'),
        deletedDateTime: null,
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
        displayName: 'Samus Aran',
        mail: 'samus.aran@domain.com',
    }, {
        classification: null,
        createdDateTime: new Date('2018-03-03'),
        deletedDateTime: null,
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
        displayName: 'King Dede',
        mail: 'king.dede@domain.com',
    }, {
        classification: null,
        createdDateTime: new Date('2018-03-03'),
        deletedDateTime: null,
        description: 'lorem ipsum',
        displayName: 'Monkey D Luffy',
        mail: 'luffy.monkey@domain.com',
    }
];

const displayNames = dataset.map(toDisplayNameView);

function toDisplayNameView(data) {
    return {
        displayName: data.displayName
    };
}

console.log(displayNames);
```